# DBus object lifecycle

Tags: python, object, lifecycle, dbus

I'm creating a python service that will receive dbus messages, create *Job* objects and return those objects to the calling application. The calling application will then use this *Job* object to receive signals from it ( when it has found something or finished working for example ).

Everything is working, I just need to know how to remove those objects from the dbus after they aren't needed anymore. In the dbus-python documentation (http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html#exporting-objects) it shows how to export an object, but not how to remove it from the bus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that the way to remove the object from the bus is just to call: `object.remove_from_connection()`

The remove_from_connection is inherited from `dbus.service.Object` which is the superclass for all dbus objects in python

Comment: Thanks! This is also quite important when writing pyunit tests for modules that expose their functions to dbus. Without using module_name.remove_from_connection() in tearDown, one gets errors of type KeyError: "Can't register the object-path handler for 'XXX':
# there is already a handler"